# Count rows inserted by SQL Bulk Copy Upload from Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I have table Call **Notification** in that table i have below columns

- ID(auto increment)
- University_Name
- Table_Name
- Number_of_Inserts

I have another table call **Student** Table in that table i have below columns

- Student_ID
- Name
- University_ID

In that DB have **University** Table also

- University_ID
- University_Name

Generally I'm **inserting** Many records at same time to **Student** Table

I want to fill **Notification** table using SQL trigger ,

so want to write SQL Trigger that can

1.count of Insertions I did in **Student** Table and insert that value to **Number_of_Inserts** column in **Notification** table

2.by getting University_ID after I insert values to **Student** Table and insert University_Name column in **Notification** table (all the University_ID will be same for bulk insertion)

Here what I tried upto now

```
  CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[Student]
FOR INSERT
AS
    declare @ID int;
    declare @University_Name varchar(100);
    declare @Table_Name archar(100);
    declare @Number_of_Inserts varchar(100);

    select @ID=i.ID from inserted i;    
    select @University_Name=i.Emp_Name from inserted i; 
    select @University_Name=i.University_Name from University where University.University_ID =University_ID from inserted i;
    SELECT @Number_of_Inserts=ROW_COUNT();  


    insert into Notification
           (ID,University_Name,Table_Name,Number_of_Inserts) 
    values(@ID,@University_Name,@Table_Name,@Number_of_Inserts);

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
GO
```

Is this possible to write this kind query within triger ?

Comment: Removed the mysql tag because the syntax is clearly SQL Server.

Comment: Your code makes zero sense.  The code has numerous errors.  You are using variables such as `@empid` which are defined nowhere.  You are using aliases such as `i.University_Name` that are not defined anywhere.

Comment: If you are inserting many rows at a time, then you need to JOIN to the inserted table instead of setting variables.   There are many examples of how to do this on the web.

Comment: @TabAlleman
to insert values I'm doing using excel file upload( SQL bulk copy upload)

when I upload a file I want to count number of insertions I did , save it as one record in notification table

Answer (score 1):

Inserted is kind of a local tabel. You can select from it inside the trigger like a normal tabel, making the trigger rather simple.

Try this instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[Student]
AFTER INSERT
AS
    INSERT Notification
           (ID,University_Name,Table_Name,Number_of_Inserts) 
    SELECT id, University_Name, Table_Name, count(*) over ()
    FROM inserted;

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
GO
```

Comment: @TabAlleman you are right, removed that part of the tekst. The real issue in the question in the attempt to use [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/)